# Read All Categories from Lotus Notes

Tags: list, task, categories, lotus-notes, appointment

is there a way to read all categories that can be assigned to appointment? 
There is a list with predefined categories and I can assign my own category(categorie1).
All that categories can be selected from "Categories" dialog.
I need this whole list in my C# project.

[image: categories list from this dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default categories are hard coded:

```
"Holiday", "Vacation", "Projects", "Clients", "Phone Calls", "Travel"
```

Add these as constants to your code.

Get the additional custom categories with key "UserCategories" from profile document "CalendarProfile".

Read the values with db.getProfileDocument() from mail db:

```
  ...
  Document doc = db.getProfileDocument("CalendarProfile", session.getUserName());
  Object userCategories = doc.getItemValue("UserCategories");
  ...
```